# Como fazer um ranking com SQL?

Tags: mysql

Bom, eu tenho uma tabela "votos_uniforme" que recebe nas colunas "voto_uniforme1", "voto_uniforme2" e "voto_uniforme3" um valor do tipo "BOOLEAN", onde 1 significa que a pessoa votou nesse uniforme e 0 o contrário, segue a imagem lógica da tabela: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com este comando:

```
SELECT(SELECT COUNT(voto_uniforme1) FROM votos_uniforme WHERE votos_uniforme.voto_uniforme1 = 1) AS Uniforme1,(SELECT COUNT(voto_uniforme2) FROM votos_uniforme WHERE votos_uniforme.voto_uniforme2 = 1) AS Uniforme2, (SELECT COUNT(voto_uniforme3) FROM votos_uniforme WHERE votos_uniforme.voto_uniforme3 = 1) AS Uniforme3
```

Ele me retorna isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas eu preciso que ele me mostre como um ranking, por exemplo quem tiver a maior quantidade de votos vem em primeiro, quem tiver a maior quantidade entre o outros dois vem em segundo, e o menor vem por último em terceiro, qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz uma etiqueta para você ter o nome do uniforme e sua quantidade e una as 3 seleções com `UNION ALL`, depois crie uma `select` para ordenação da quantidade, ***exemplo***:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT COUNT(voto_uniforme1) as quantidade, 'uniforme1' as uniforme 
        FROM votos_uniforme WHERE votos_uniforme.voto_uniforme1 = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(voto_uniforme2) as quantidade, 'uniforme2' as uniforme 
        FROM votos_uniforme WHERE votos_uniforme.voto_uniforme2 = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(voto_uniforme3) as quantidade, 'uniforme3' as uniforme 
        FROM votos_uniforme WHERE votos_uniforme.voto_uniforme3 = 1)
AS t ORDER BY quantidade desc
```

nesse caso vai gerar 3 linhas com a ordenação pela quantidade, diferente daquela que gerava somente uma linha.

Para criação da `View` tem que ser sem o `SELECT` mais externo (não aceita a criação de View com `Sub Query`), exemplo de criação:

```
CREATE VIEW `db`.`View1` AS

    SELECT COUNT(voto_uniforme1) as quantidade, 'uniforme1' as uniforme 
            FROM votos_uniforme WHERE votos_uniforme.voto_uniforme1 = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(voto_uniforme2) as quantidade, 'uniforme2' as uniforme 
            FROM votos_uniforme WHERE votos_uniforme.voto_uniforme2 = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(voto_uniforme3) as quantidade, 'uniforme3' as uniforme 
            FROM votos_uniforme WHERE votos_uniforme.voto_uniforme3 = 1
```

e no momento da sua utilização no `SELECT` da chamada da sua `View` coloque a ***ordenação***, **exemplo**:

```
SELECT * FROM View1 ORDER BY quantidade DESC
```

Comment: No caso esse "DESC" ordena do maior para o menor ?

Comment: @LoneTonberry isso do maior para o menor, se quiser em ordem normal retire o `DESC` ou coloque `ASC`

Comment: Me apareceu um erro, é que eu preciso fazer uma VIEW com esse código e quando tento salvar como uma VIEW mostra esse error: "#1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause"

Comment: @LoneTonberry bom ai você colocou mais um ponto, para criação da view fiz o edit explicando, observe na resposta como deve ser criado e como deve ser utilizado com ordenação, é um exemplo.

Comment: Então no caso, a ordenação não pode fazer parte da view de nenhuma forma ?

Comment: @LoneTonberry não, porque isso te privaria de utilizar a `View` para outros fins, como filtros, ordernação e assim por diante (é normal isso nos bancos). Se você quiser utilizar um Procedimento (Procedure) ai conseguiria!